# Why do we need double braces in this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am a beginner of JavaScript and confused why we need a double braces in `style{{display: '', justifyContent: ''}}`. Also I am confused when I should use `return ()` and `return {}`.

```
import React from 'react';

const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        //navigation 'Sign Out' on top right
        <nav style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
            <p>Sign Out</p>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you're writing **JSX** which looks like an HTML but with javascript syntax.

(JSX stands for JavaScript XML. JSX allows us to write HTML in React. JSX makes it easier to write and add HTML in React.)

So, when you want to reference a Javascript object in JSX, you use `{}`, let's say you have this:

```js
const text = 'Hi There!';
```

and you want that text to be rendered in an HTML `<p>` tag, you'd write something like this:

```js
<p> { text } </p>
```

In this case : `style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}`, the first `{}` indicate that you want to reference a javascript variable, and the second `{ display: ... }` is the javascript variable itself. (Styles in JSX are defined as object which is different from HTML style attribute that takes string).

the second part regarding returning `{}` or `()` is very straightforward, you use `()` when you have a multi line return statement, and use `{}` when you are just returning a normal (literal) javascript object.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is not JS, this is specific to ReactJS and style [Inline Styling ReactJS](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
```

Here the outside brackets {} is denote a varible example

```
const nameOfClass="some-class"
className={nameOfclass}
//or directly
className="some-class"
```

Second one denote an object

```
const styleExample={color: 'blue'};
<div style={styleExample} >
//or we can directly write
<div style={{color: 'blue'}} >
```

for when to use ( vs {

```
// here we use ( to avoid that it get confused with just return
//this will work
return (
 <p> test </p>
);
```

this will not work always (and can confuse reader
we can't tell if is return (nothing, undefined) or
return what we find in the next line, rember that
there were no confusing in the first example

```
return  
 <p> test </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ReactJS and the syntax is called [jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Answer (score 0):

### Why do you need two curly braces?

First curly braces are special syntax in JSX. It is used to evaluate a JavaScript expression during compilation. A JavaScript expression can be a variable, function, an object, or any code that resolves into a value.

Second one is a JSON object which represents the styling properties.

### When do you use parenthesis?

Parenthesis are used to group multiline of codes on JavaScript returnstatement so to prevent semicolon inserted automatically in the wrong place.

It is not necessary to add a semicolon in JavaScript. JavaScript engine automatically inserts a semicolon at the first possible opportunity on a line after a return statement. If the JavaScript engine places the semicolon where it should not be, your code won’t compile.

```js
class StarsComponent {
  constructor(size) {
    this.size = size;
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>  // <--JavaScript engine inserts semicolon here
           *
           </div>
  }
}
```

```js
class StarsComponent {
  constructor(size) {
    this.size = size;
  }
  
  render() {
    return (<div> 
            *
            </div>) // <--JavaScript engine inserts semicolon here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `style={}` is roughly equivalent to `style:` in the transpiled JS.

```
import React from 'react';

const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        //navigation 'Sign Out' on top right
        <nav style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
            <p>Sign Out</p>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Navigation;
```

becomes

```js
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = void 0;

var _react = _interopRequireDefault(require("react"));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    /*#__PURE__*/
    //navigation 'Sign Out' on top right
    _react.default.createElement("nav", {
      style: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
      }
    }, /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement("p", null, "Sign Out"))
  );
};

var _default = Navigation;
exports.default = _default;
```

So with one set of braces, we're saying:

`React.createElement('nav', { style: display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end' })` which is a syntax error.

with two sets of braces:

`React.createElement('nav', { style: {display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }})`

### References

- [Babel.js Playground for link](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4A5FAN2AHMUZha4BeOAAoAlPwB8cAN7k4suERgBXKDSEy5GgPSaarDlx6r8AZQ6qA8opj44vGBDDyOACxjqNsgDy6WcBgE8AGyQ-SUkAE2A6MECUfwAuAkxggA98ABo4ACtFBmBMfwBhWhgkGhhE_GSkFIBaMvD8AF8msXcPDU8wMVN2CytPTW72zp1WNo1hCibKGshYOHCkTBRFQKY9Tm5aUiA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.10.5&externalPlugins=)